# How to change tabnine autocompletion shortcut in VS code?

Tags: tabnine

I am on windows, and I use vscode.
I have:
TAB: to accept
ALT+] to have other suggestions.
I want to change ALT+] to ALT+SPACE.
How to do that.
I opened shortcuts and search for tabnine.
There is the shorcut for accept but not other suggestion.
Please help!